# Ember.js this.super() what is the purpose

Tags: ember.js

Lot of times i see the function

```
init: function() {
    return this._super();
  },
```

What is the purpose of this function and when to use them? 
Can someone explain to me practically use?

Answer (score 10):

Calling `this._super()` in the `init` calls the `init` function of the superclass.

The [documentation gives this example](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/):

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  say: function(thing) {
    var name = this.get('name');
    alert(name + " says: " + thing);
  }
});

App.Soldier = App.Person.extend({
  say: function(thing) {
    this._super(thing + ", sir!");
  }
});

var yehuda = App.Soldier.create({
  name: "Yehuda Katz"
});

yehuda.say("Yes"); // alerts "Yehuda Katz says: Yes, sir!"
```